# Publishing CSS file in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, css, iis

I am new at using IIS. I have published my ASP.NET Application into the IIS server, the application uses a third party HTML loader, which loads the HTML but does not apply the effects from the .css file when I have published. I add the following in the head tag of the HTML

```
<link href="~/input/docgenix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I have kept the CSS file in the input folder of the published application.

On the other hand if add the HTML from source of some preexisting page from the internet along with a link to its CSS file the effects of the CSS file can be seen in effect. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css">
```

My guess is that my CSS is not being published along with my application. Please help me out. How can I publishh this CSS file properly?

Answer (score 2):

The `~` part of the file path (which means "application root") isn't recognised client-side.

You have two options - generate the `<link>` element server-side (`runat="server"`) and populate the `href` attribute there (where `~` is recognised, using `Page.ResolveUrl()`), or alternatively construct an appropriate relative path that doesn't include the tilde (which is probably more efficient).

**Relative path**

Probably just need to lose the tilde (`~`) if you application is hosted at the domain root level:

```
<link href="/input/docgenix.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Server side solution:**

This will work irrespective of whether the web application is hosted at domain root level or within a folder (`mysite.com/myapp` vs `mysite.com`) but is probably a little less efficient.

In the markup:

```
<link id="lnk" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and in the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lnk.Attributes["href"] = Page.ResolveUrl("~/input/docgenix.css");
    }
}
```

(Note: this is untested)

Comment: how do u suggest i make that path??

Comment: Updated my answer with examples.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this? :

```
<link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/input/docgenix.css") %>"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```